# Laravel post form error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm having a problem for the first time when i submit a form.

When i submit the form it doesn't go to post route and i don't know why.

my post route is that:

```
    Route::post('/app/add-new-db', function()
  {
    $rules = array(
          'name' => 'required|min:4',
          'file' => 'required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {

      // get the error messages from the validator
      $messages = $validator->messages();

      // redirect our user back to the form with the errors from the validator
      return Redirect::to('app/add-new-db')
         ->withErrors($validator);

     }
     else
     {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        $fname = pathinfo(Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fext = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        echo $fname.$fext;
        //Input::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/dbs/', $fname.$fext);

        /*
        DB::connection('mysql')->insert('insert into databases (name, logotipo) values (?, ?)',
         [$name, $fname.$fext]);
         */
       //return Redirect::to('app/settings/');
     }
  });
```

And my html:

```
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col content">
  {!! Form::open(['url'=>'app/add-new-db', 'files'=>true]) !!}
  <div class="mdl-grid no-verticall">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
      <h4>Adicionar Base de Dados</h4>
      <div class="divider"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Nome: ') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['id'=> 'name', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Logotipo:') !!}
        {!! Form::file('image', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        @if ($errors->has('image'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span>
        @endIf
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Adicionar', ['id'=>'add-new-db', 'class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}
        <p class="text-success"><?php echo Session::get('success'); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

I'm loading this from from a jquery get:

```
    function addDB()
   {
     $( "#settings-new-db" ).click(function(e)
     {
       $.get('/app/add-new-db', function(response)
       {
          $('.content-settings').html("");
          $('.content-settings').html(response);
          componentHandler.upgradeDom();
       });
       e.preventDefault();
     });
   }
```

When i try to submit the form i'm getting 302 found in network console from chrome.

I'm doing forms at this way and it is happens for the first time. Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the method to post.

Comment: If i inspect the html, i have this <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/app/add-new-db" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="HC5D8DMqAHdEoqt0AnsXjYx0VvROy8qD1IWUVZFm"> @aynber

Comment: Post is the default method, there is no prob with that. Make sure you can access the `app/add-new-db` directly from your browser. I suspect some kind of redirect with the 302 error.

Comment: yes, i can access directly from browser.
If i submit form, i have 302 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the name attribute for your image upload field. You refer it as `image` in the form but you are trying to fetch it as `file` in your controller.

Comment: Hmm, i've updated the answer with another minor fix that it may causes this.

Comment: It probably returns you back because of the validator. You've marked your `file` input as required but there is nowhere to be found in your post request, because you've accidently named it `image` in your form.

Comment: @user3242861 This is strange. Still getting `302 Found` then? Please update your question with your latest code.

Comment: You are right! The problem was the name image. That works now!